# How to add something visual to a jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have defined a class called Stone to add graphical stones to a JPanel:

```
public class Stone {

    private int x, y;
    private Color color;

    private static final int radius = 18;

    Stone(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Stone(int x, int y, Color color) {
        this(color);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);

        g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }

    void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I want to draw them on a JPanel. Do I have to do this within the paint method of JPanel or is it possible to use the add method of JPanel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick answer is that you should extend a `JComponent` (because you want to add it to `JPanel`) and override the `paintComponent` method (because you want some custom painting of your object).

Comment: @Boro Say you're painting an image. Do you know if this would work properly with a JScrollPane? I mean display the scrollbars if the dimensions are bigger than the display area.

Comment: @JamesPoulson it will work fine as long as you make sure the component (`JLabel` preferably) which you use to paint the image has always size corresponding to the image. Then you put it into a `JScrollPane` and it will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I will test this. The approach I was using was to use a `JLabel`'s icon to display a high resolution image and the text as null. Not sure if this is efficient memory wise. One advantage is that this respects the limits of the scroll pane whereas a repaint (not paintComponent) can cause some "bleeding" over neighbouring components.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing to try is to make your `Stone` class extend JComponent, rename draw() to [paintComponent()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) and add a `Stone` instance to your JPanel.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to do with it on the screen. As the others mentioned you could inherit from JComponent, which could be a good choice if the user wants to interact with it in some way.

A more light-weight approach could be to implement the Shape interface, or provide a method getShape().

You could use the ShapeIcon I wrote some time ago, to add it to a JLabel:
http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/icon/ShapeIcon.html

Then add the JLabel to the JPanel.

But maybe instead of adding individual Stone icons to individual JLabels, you want to draw an image first and show that in the JPanel?

If you could tell us more about your goals we could help you better.

Comment: actually at some later point I would like to drag the stones, so I would need to implement mouse listener...I will discuss this tomorrow with a friend at university, I am actually not sure if we are allowed to extend the stone class itself

Comment: Note that some time ago, I wrote a framework to customize (e.g. drag) components on the screen. E.g. you could add a JXIconCustomizer to a JCustomizerPane. See the first part of a tutorial here: http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/tutorial/swing/customizer/index.html
(The samples currently can't be executed from the server due to some configuration issues.)
http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/JXIconCustomizer.html